# Help with JSON structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following javascript which I need to make dynamic.

```
data.addRows(2);
data.setValue(0, 0, 'name goes here');
data.setValue(0, 1, value 1 goes here); 
data.setValue(0, 2, value 2 goes here); 
data.setValue(1, 0, 'name goes here');
data.setValue(1, 1, value 1 goes here); 
data.setValue(1, 2, value 2 goes here);
```

I guess a loop is the best way to go forward:

I have come up with the following json structure:

```
[ 
    {"User1":{"value1": 50.00,"value2": "100"}}, 
    {"User2":{"value1": 10.00,"value2": "20"}}, 
    {"User3":{"value1": 10.00,"value2": "20"}}, 
    {"User4":{"value1": 10.00,"value2": "20"}}, 
    {"User5":{"value1": 20.00,"value2": "40"}} 
]
```

I think this structure needs improving.  Can someone please suggest a better structure to make it very easy for me to extract the data I want to extract from this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var dataset = [
  {uid: 'user1', value1: 50.00, value2: 100},
  {uid: 'user2', value1: 10.00, value2: 20}, 
];
```

That way you can do `data.length` to figure out how many values you have and you can loop a bit easier. For example:

```
for(i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
   console.log(data[i].uid);
}
```

Using your example:

```
data.addRows(2); 
var l = dataset.length, i, x = 0, y = 0;
for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  data.setValue(y, x, dataset[i].uid); x++;
  data.setValue(y, x, dataset[i].value1); x++;
  data.setValue(y, x, dataset[i].value2); x=0;
  y++;
}
```

Comment: I have made the necessary changes to the JSON structure, but can't seem to loop through it to get it into the javascript above.

Comment: I've modified my answer to show you one possible solution. It's by no means the best way of keeping track of x and y, but it should work fine for what you need.

Comment: Seems to be working so far!  Testing it out right now.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't see that you could make it anymore simple, unless there's something special about the data that would allow repeated parts to be separated out in some fashion.

Comment: The reason why I am asking, is because I am having difficulty trying to loop through the data to make the javascript above dynamic.

Comment: The reason you are having difficulty is because it looks like you are using a unique key (user1,user2,user3) as the key for the data associated. By creating uid and setting it to user1, now you have a single way of referencing any user.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
{"users": [
    {"value1": 50, "value2": 100},
    {"value1": 10, "value2": 20},
    {"value1": 10, "value2": 20},
    {"value1": 10, "value2": 20},
    {"value1": 20, "value2": 40}
]}
```

Or, if you want to have your users have IDs:

```
{"users": {
    "userId1": {"value1": 50, "value2": 100},
    "userId2": {"value1": 10, "value2": 20},
    "userId3": {"value1": 10, "value2": 20},
    "userId4": {"value1": 10, "value2": 20},
    "userId5": {"value1": 20, "value2": 40}
}}
```

Remember, all numbers in JavaScript are floating-point numbers.

Comment: This JSON wouldn't be very helpful because you can't tie the values to any specific user.

Comment: Each value pair is for a specific user, I don't think this will work.

Comment: In your second example, does it become easier to loop through that to stick the data into the javascript example I gave above?

Comment: Edited to add IDs. With this, you can access it either sequentially (`for (var user in data.users) { ... }`) or randomly (`data.users["userId1"].value1`).

Comment: If all you want to do is loop through it sequentially, Angelo R.'s solution works well, and it has the added advantage of an easily-accessible `length`. But mine allows both forms of access easily.

Comment: I'm not having much luck looping through Angelo R.'s example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this, the idea is from ColdFusion SerializeJson()

I assume your data is like a table

```
user        value1        value2
------------------------------------
user1       50            100
user2       10            20
...
```

the json structure is

```
{"COLUMNS":["USER","VALUE1","VALUE2"],"DATA":[["user1",50.0,100.0],["user2",10.0,20.0]]}
```

more clear reading

```
{
    "COLUMNS":
        [
            "USER",
            "VALUE1",
            "VALUE2"
        ],
    "DATA":
        [
            [
                "user1",
                50.0,
                100.0
            ],
            [
                "user2",
                10.0,
                20.0
            ]
        ]
}
```

with this structure, we know that every varname.DATA[index][0] is refers to USER

Answer (score 0):

Check this link for [json encoding](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/data/json_encode.php)

And for now your json value should be encoded like this

```
{"id":8,"heading":"heading goes here","content":"&lt;p&gt;content goes here&lt;\/p&gt;"}
```

Sorry not for you....